# weird mistake on my php server

Tags: php, function, php-parse-error

I have some trouble in my php server,

I have a page that is includes using the function include

this page is called validation.phtml

then in that page I call a function that I did like that:

```
<?php echo recordTravauxDemandeDevis(); ?>
```

when I go on that page,

it return to me

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'recordTravauxDemandeDevis' (T_STRING) in /htdocs/p/validation_demande_devis.phtml on line 1

I do not know what I did wrong.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Edit : below is my function

```
/**
 * Fonction d'enregistrement d'une demande de devis
 * @return null
 */
function recordTravauxDemandeDevis() {
//    verifie si le formulaire est posté
    if (isset($_POST['nom'])) {
        //on démarre les transactions
        mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
        mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");


        //On échappe les variables
        $error = 0;
        //variable n° de demande
        $id_demande = time();

        //variables infos generales
        $civilite = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['civilite']);
        $nom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nom']);
        $prenom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prenom']);
        if (!isset($_POST['raison_sociale'])) {
            $raison_sociale = '';
        } else {
            $raison_sociale = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['raison_sociale']);
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['siret'])) {
            $siret = '';
        } else {
            $siret = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['siret']);
        }
        if (!isset($_POST['no_tva'])) {
            $no_tva = '';
        } else {
            $no_tva = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['no_tva']);
        }
        $type_demande = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type_travaux']);
        $permis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['permis']);
        $budget = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['budget']);

        $query1 = "INSERT INTO `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales` SET
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_id_demande` = '{$id_demande}',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_nom` = '{$nom}',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_prenom` = '{$prenom}',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_raison_sociale` = '{$raison_sociale}',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_siret` = '{$siret}',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_no_tva` = '{$no_tva}',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_etat` = '0',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_type` = '{$type_demande}',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_permis` = '{$permis}',
            `spb_demande_devis_infos_generales_budget` = '{$budget}'    
            ";
        mysql_query($query1);
        if (mysql_error()) {
            ++$error;
        }

        //Échappement des variables d'adresse de facturation
        $adresse_fac_line1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_fac_line1']);
        $adresse_fac_line2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_fac_line2']);
        $adresse_fac_line3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_fac_line3']);
        $adresse_fac_line4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_fac_line4']);
        $adresse_fac_line5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_fac_line5']);
        $adresse_fac_line6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_fac_line6']);

        $query2 = "INSERT INTO `spb_demande_devis_adresses` SET
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_id_demande` = '{$id_demande}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ligne1` = '{$adresse_fac_line1}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ligne2` = '{$adresse_fac_line2}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ligne3` = '{$adresse_fac_line3}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ligne4` = '{$adresse_fac_line4}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_cp` = '{$adresse_fac_line5}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ville` = '{$adresse_fac_line6}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_facturation` = '1',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_chantier` = '0'
            ";
        mysql_query($query2);
        if (mysql_error()) {
            ++$error;
        }

        $adresse_cha_line1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_cha_line1']);
        $adresse_cha_line2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_cha_line2']);
        $adresse_cha_line3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_cha_line3']);
        $adresse_cha_line4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_cha_line4']);
        $adresse_cha_line5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_cha_line5']);
        $adresse_cha_line6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adresse_cha_line6']);

        $query3 = "INSERT INTO `spb_demande_devis_adresses` SET
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_id_demande` = '{$id_demande}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ligne1` = '{$adresse_cha_line1}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ligne2` = '{$adresse_cha_line2}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ligne3` = '{$adresse_cha_line3}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ligne4` = '{$adresse_cha_line4}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_cp` = '{$adresse_cha_line5}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_ville` = '{$adresse_cha_line6}',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_facturation` = '0',
            `spb_demande_devis_adresses_chantier` = '1'
            ";
        mysql_query($query3);
        if (mysql_error()) {
            ++$error;
        }

        //échappement des variables de coordonnées
        $tel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tel']);
        $mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
        $mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
        $horaire_contact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['horaire_contact']);

        $query4 = "INSERT INTO `spb_demande_devis_coordonnees` SET
                    `spb_demande_devis_coordonnees_id_demande` = '{$id_demande}',
                    `spb_demande_devis_coordonnees_tel` = '{$tel}',
                    `spb_demande_devis_coordonnees_mobile` = '{$mobile}',
                    `spb_demande_devis_coordonnees_mail` = '{$mail}',
                    `spb_demande_devis_coordonnees_horaires` = '{$horaire_contact}'
                  ";
        mysql_query($query4);
        if (mysql_error()) {
            ++$error;
        }

        foreach ($_POST['travaux'] as $travaux) {
            //nettoyage des variables
            $prestation = mysql_real_escape_string($travaux['nom_prestation']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO `spb_demande_devis_type_travaux` SET
                            `spb_demande_devis_type_travaux_id_demande` = '{$id_demande}',
                            `spb_demande_devis_type_travaux` = '{$prestation}'
                          ";

            //on balance sur le server
            mysql_query($query);
            if (mysql_error()) {
                ++$error;
            }
        }

        //nettoyage des variables de description
        $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['texte_description']);

        $query5 = "INSERT INTO `spb_demande_devis_divers` SET
            `spb_demande_devis_divers_id_demande` = '{$id_demande}',
            `spb_demande_devis_divers_description` = '{$description}'
            ";
        mysql_query($query5);
        if (mysql_error()) {
            ++$error;
        }

        //On verifie les erreurs, si tout est ok comit, sinon rollback

        if ($error == 0) {
            //si y'a pas d'erreurs on comit
            mysql_query("COMMIT");
            $message = '<div class="success">Votre demande de devis a bien été enregistrée. Notre équipe vous contactera prochainement afin de prendre en charge votre projet. Nous vous remercions de la confiance que vous nous avez accordé.</div>';
        } else {
            //sinon rollback
            mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
            $message = '<div class="error">Erreur lors de l\'enregistrement, veuillez réessayer dans quelques minutes. i le problème persiste, contactez l\'administrateur du site.</div>';
        }
    } else {
        //on renvoit vers la page du formulaire
        header('location:index.php?p=demande-devis');
        $message = null;
    }
    return $message;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your recordTravauxDemandeDevis() function.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just edited my initial post

Comment: At first glance, it doesn't seem that there's anything wrong in your function. Can you show the code behind the include please?

Comment: The issue is in /htdocs/p/validation_demande_devis.phtml you should just post that without any modification.  If I had to guess I'd say: you're using a .phtml file extension for some reason, did you make sure to open it with a <?php open tag?  Alternatively, perhaps you could post the code on ideone.com and get a reduced test case.

Comment: what does the code before the `echo recordTravauxDemandeDevis();` look like? PHP is saying that it's unable to parse the file **up to** that point.

Comment: the code before the call of the function is html `<h3><img src="images/accept.png"> Validation de votre demande de devis</h3>

<p><br></p>   
<?php echo recordTravauxDemandeDevis(); ?>`

Comment: @Kzqai If PHP wasn't used to read its .phtml file, it wouldn't trigger this PHP error I think :)

Comment: when I remove, the php code, I have no mistake, but the thing is that I need that code.

Comment: PHP tells you that the syntax error is on line 1. Did you write `<h3><img src="images/accept.png"> Validation de votre demande de devis</h3> <p><br></p> <?php echo recordTravauxDemandeDevis(); ?>` on one line only ?

Comment: no, I mean, there is nothing wrong If it was written in one line, because the code is compiled

Comment: Check that there are no unprintable characters between `echo` and `recordTravauxDemandeDevis`, just delete everything in between and make a space.

Comment: it seems that there is no unprintable characteres as netbeans shows http://i.stack.imgur.com/PnJEO.png

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski Do you include the php file with definition of your function? It might also happen that function name has non-ascii symbols.

Comment: yes I do, and it works fine for all function, in fact this is a validation form control, the initial page is index.php?p=demande-devis then on that page I have a form action="index.php?p=validation-devis" which is the page that show that error

Comment: Please upload the file which includes call to the function.

Comment: You said the code is compiled. Did you try without minifying it ?

Comment: I do noy minify it, php do the compilation

Comment: I don't get the "compilation made by PHP" thing, sorry. What do you mean ? When you do a syntax error, PHP shows you (most of the time) the real line where it occurs.

Comment: Do you want to say that the phtml file is writteb by PHP ? Can you show us the content of this very one file because what you displayed in your screenshot was a .php file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you are posting the 'nom' value and therefore you must be entering into the else case and headering the new location. I am thinking you would get the error when attempting to echo the unitialized $message after you have already sent the header. Try changing to..

```
     <?php  $message =  recordTravauxDemandeDevis();
     if(isset($message)){
         echo $message;
     }else{
         header('location:index.php?p=demande-devis');
     }
```

And remove the header call from your function